# dotnet new install template from remote url

Tags: .net, azure

I have installed a solution template locally for dotnet new command:

```
dotnet new -–install <local_solution_path>
```

Which is working fine, because I can create new solution from that template.

Now, I would like to know if I can install template from remote url, like below:

```
dotnet new -–install <remote_solution_path>
```

My question is if there is any way to use remote solution path to install dotnet new templates? I am using Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Install a custom template from a NuGet package on any NuGet feed by referencing a nupkg file directly or by specifying a file system directory that contains a templating configuration.

> My question is if there is any way to use remote solution path to install dotnet new templates?

AFAIK, you could install a template from a NuGet package stored at **nuget.org**, a **local nupkg file** and a **file system directory**.

For more details, you could read this [article](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/custom-templates.md).